# Copy duplicate numbers to another cell or google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, count, duplicates, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

On one google sheet, I have a page which auto fills with data in column A. On another sheet, I'm trying to put in a formula that not only counts duplicate numbers, but also shows which numbers are duplicated and how many times. For example, number 7734 is in five different rows on Sheet 1, how can I then have two columns on Sheet 2 that shows 7734    5 (or similar)?
Many thanks.

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet so we have some data to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY('Sheet 2'!A:A, 
 "select A,count(A) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A 
  label count(A)''", 0), 
 "where Col2 >= 2", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfect, and I would never have been able to think of that! Many thanks @player0!